# .NET 5 IOptionsSnapshot: Cannot resolve scoped service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-5

I get the following Exception when I try to resolve the IOptionsSnapshot service:

> 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot`1[Test.MyOptions]' from root provider.'

I leave the test code down below, if someone can tell me the problem.

**Main**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("MyOptions.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var provider = services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions))).BuildServiceProvider(true);

        var test = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<MyOptions>>();
    }
}
```

**MyOptions class**

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

**MyOptions.json**

```
{
  "MyOptions": {
    "Value": 10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IOptionsSnapshot<T>` is registered as a *scoped* service, which means you need to create a service scope and then resolve using that:

```
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var scopedProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var test = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<MyOptions>>();

   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When consuming `IOptions<>` from a singleton and you want to make use of automatic config reloads, you should use `IOptionsMonitor<>` instead of `IOptionsSnapshot<>` as advised here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2380#issuecomment-358505218